# Error occurs when updating values of a nested dictionary in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, dictionary, error-handling, dolphindb

As shown in the following script, I want to update values of a nested dictionary “d2“:

```
d1 = dict( STRING, ANY )
d2 = dict( STRING, ANY )
d2[`d2_K] = 1
d1[`d1_K] = d2
d1[`d1_K][`d2_K] = 3
```

But when I executed the last line of code, I encountered an error: `Please use '==' rather than '=' as equal operator in non-sql expression`.

I tried an alternative approach:

```
d1 = dict( STRING, ANY )
d2 = dict( STRING, ANY )

d2[`d2_K] = 1
d1[`d1_K] = d2
d2[`d2_K] = 3
```

But another error was reported: `Object without ownership could not be modified`.

Could someone explain the causes behind these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first error occurs because assignment operation is not supported
   in `d1[`d1_K][`d2_K] = 3`.
2. The second error occurs because “d2[`d2_K]” is read-only and cannot
   be modified.